# Extract 3 substrings and create Animal Object

Tags: java

I am currently working on my '**`readDataFromFile()`**' method which reads texts files such as:

```
Bird    Golden Eagle    Eddie
Mammal  Tiger   Tommy
Mammal  Lion    Leo
Bird    Parrot  Polly
Reptile Cobra   Colin
```

- How would I go about extracting **`3 substrings`** and then create and add an **`Animal object`** to the **`Zoo`**.
- An Animal object has: name and species.

I have 2 classes: `Zoo and Animal`. Any help on this subject would be amazing.

Zoo Class:

```
public class MyZoo
{
   private String zooId;
   private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
   private TreeMap<String, Animal> animals;
   private Animal animal;

   public MyZoo(String zooId)
   {
      this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
      nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
      animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>();
   }

   public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
      animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
      this.animal = animal;
   }

   public void readDataFromFile() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      int noOfAnimalsRead = 0;

      String fileName = null;

      JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
      FileDialog fileDialogBox = new FileDialog(mainWindow, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fileDialogBox.setDirectory("."); 
      fileDialogBox.setVisible(true);

      fileName = fileDialogBox.getFile();
      String directoryPath = fileDialogBox.getDirectory();

      File dataFile = new File (fileName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

      scanner.next();
      while(scanner.hasNext())
       {
       String name = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Animal: " + name);
       }

      scanner.close();
   }
```

Animal Class:

```
public class Animal
{
   private String id;
   private String species;
   private String name;
   public Animal(String species, String name, MyZoo owner)
   {
      id = owner.allocateId();
      this.species = species;
      this.name  = name;
   }

   public String getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public String getSpecies()
   {
      return species;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return id + "  " + name + ": a " + species;
   }
}
```

Comment: How are the columns divided? Are tabs used?

Comment: You should use the `split()` method.

Comment: Yes tabs are used to separate each piece of data. I'll do some digging into the 'split()' method. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Split the input into lines, then split each line into fields. Both can be done using [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html).

```
String input = "Bird\tGolden Eagle\tEddie\n"
        + "Mammal\tTiger\tTommy\n"
        + "Mammal\tLion\tLeo\n"
        + "Bird\tParrot\tPolly\n"
        + "Reptile\tCobra\tColin";

MyZoo zoo = new MyZoo();

for (String line : input.split("\n")) {
    String[] parts = line.split("\t");
    Animal animal = new Animal(parts[1], parts[2], zoo);
    System.out.println(animal);
}
```

Output:

```
some-random-id  Eddie: a Golden Eagle
some-random-id  Tommy: a Tiger
some-random-id  Leo: a Lion
some-random-id  Polly: a Parrot
some-random-id  Colin: a Cobra
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with this line when compiling: MyZoo zoo = new MyZoo();, It highlights the 'new MyZoo();' section with the error saying, Constructor MyZoo in class MyZoo cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: Yes, I did not use your `MyZoo` implementation but a simplified version. Just use the `new MyZoo(zooId)` constructor instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help, ill assess the code so that i fully understand how it works. :)